# Mapping specific letters onto a list of words

Tags: list, python-3.x

Can someone please suggest an approach to write the piece of codes that will automatically maps the letter in letter_str onto the dic_key (a dict key string type that contains dashes that match the  length of words in word_lst)?

So, the mapping only occurs if a letter appears in every words in the list at the same position no matter how many words is in the list.

If no letter appears at any position for all the words in the word list then the new_dic_key would be '----'. Please see the examples below

Thanks

```
word_lst = ['ague', 'bute', 'byre', 'came', 'case', 'doze']
dic_key = '----'
letters_str ='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

new_dic_key = '---e'
```

if

```
word_list = ['bute', 'byre']

new_dic_key = 'b--e'
```

or

```
word_list = ['drek', 'drew', 'dyes']

new_dic_key = 'd-e-'
```

Comment: Your question is basically pseudo code, have you tried to work it out?

Comment: Will all the words in `word_list` be of the same length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the words in the `word_list` will be of the same length this code will give what you want:

```
word_list = ['drek', 'drew', 'dyes']
cols = []
for i in range(len(word_list[0])):
    cols.append([])

for word in word_list:
    for i, ch in enumerate(word):
        cols[i].append(ch)

pattern = [item[0] if len(set(item)) == 1 else '-' for item in cols]
print ''.join(pattern)
d-e-
```

**Explanation**:

We initialize `cols` to be a list of list. It will contain two dimensional representation of the letters in the words of `word_list`. After populating `cols` this is what it looks like:

```
[['d', 'd', 'd'], ['r', 'r', 'y'], ['e', 'e', 'e'], ['k', 'w', 's']]
```

So the final result `new_dic_key` will contain the letter only if all elements in the sub-list above have the same letter, otherwise it will contain a `-`. This is achieved using the list comprehension for `pattern`.

Hope it helps.